# Character Values for Alternating Groups of degree $\geq 7$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Is it true that in each row and column of the character table of alternating groups with degree $\geq 7$ there are at most two complex values? Any reference will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean *non-real* when you say *complex*? A Magma calculation indicates that actually a stronger property might hold: For all alternating groups of degree $\le35$, there are at most $2$ non-rational values in each row and column. Actually, it suffices to show the assertion either for the rows, or for the columns, by using Brauer's Theorem for the Galois action on the irreducible characters and the conjugacy classes.

Comment: @PeterMueller : I believe that the answer to your stronger question should be found (one way or other) in the proof of the result of James and Kerber I mention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Geoff thought, the answer is contained in James and Kerber (it's Theorem 2.5.13 in "The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group", Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications vol. 16, 1981).

Each row or column of the character table contains at most one pair of irrationalities.

If $\lambda$ is a self-conjugate partition (and so corresponds to an irreducible character of $S_n$ that splits on restriction to $A_n$), then the only cycle type of elements where the corresponding character values are irrational is the one with cycle lengths equal to the lengths of the hooks centred on the main diagonal of the Young diagram (notice that these are all odd and distinct, so correspond to a conjugacy class of $S_n$ that splits in $A_n$).

For example, for the partition $(6,6,6,6,6,6)$ this cycle type would be $[11,9,7,5,3,1]$.

Answer (score 5):

Answer amended due to useful comment of Peter Mueller ( so should be unaccepted, as there may be a better one).
  In a 1994 Journal of Algebra paper, John Thompson and I determined the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the values of its irreducible characters. For large enough $n$, this can contain an arbitrarily large number of complex quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.
  However, as Peter Mueller points out, this does not, of itself, answer the question posed here.
  A key Lemma used in the above paper was a Lemma of James and Kerber ( in Encyclopedia of Mathematics) determines the extension $\mathbb{Q}[\{\chi(g): \chi \in {\rm Irr}(G) \}].$ This is always (at most) a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. However, it would take a detailed examination of the proof of that Lemma of James and Kerber to see whether there can be more that two irreducible characters $\chi$ with $\chi(g)$ non-real.

Later edit: Jeremy Rickard explains in his answer exactly what the Lemma of James and Kerber says about the question.

Comment: Apparently I'm missing the point -- why does that answer the question?

Comment: @PeterMueller :Mmm, thanks, you are right that it doesn't explicitly answer the question as it stands ( I slightly misread the question). I need to check out the key lemma from James and Kerber used in the referenced paper with Thompson to see whether that covers things. The Lemma of James and Kerber states that if $g \in A_{n}$ has all its disjoint cycles of distinct odd length, then the field generated by the character values at $g$ is a genuinely quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. In any case, the answer to the question lies in that result of James and Kerber.

Comment: @PeterMueller : The easiest way would be show that for such a suitably chosen $g$, there might be more than two irreducible characters $\chi$ with $\chi(g)$ non-real. But it is conceivable that there is always just one complex conjugate pair of irreducible characters with this property. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that book at the moment, but I'm sure someone on here will.

Answer (score 3):

This answer essentially summarizes information from the other answers, hopefully, making the whole picture clear. For each self-conjugate partition $\lambda$ (i.e., $\lambda=\lambda'$) of $n$, the irreducible character $\chi_\lambda$ of $S_n$ is a sum of two irreducible representations of $A_n$: $\chi_\lambda = \chi_\lambda^+ + \chi_\lambda^-$. Also, for each partition with distinct odd parts $\mu=(2m_1+1,\dotsc,2m_d+1)$, where $m_1>\dotsb >m_d$ the conjugacy class $C_\mu$ of elements with cycle type $\mu$ in $S_n$ splits into two $A_n$-conjugacy classes, represented by elements $w_\mu^+$ and $w_\mu^-$.

There is a bijective correspondence $\lambda\mapsto \phi(\lambda)$ from the set of self-conjugate partitions onto the set of partitions with distinct odd parts. The image of $\lambda$ is $\mu=(2m_1+1,\dotsc,2m_d+1)$ if the number of boxes in the Young diagram of $\lambda$ strictly to the right (or strictly below) a box of the form $(i,i)$ is $m_i$.

**Theorem.** All character values of $A_n$ are real except possibly those of the form $\chi_{\lambda}^\pm(w_\mu^\pm)$, where $\mu=\phi(\lambda)=(2m_1+1,\dotsc,2m_d+1)$.
The character value $\chi_{\lambda^\pm}(w_\mu^\pm)$ is not real if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^d m_i$ is odd.

It follows that, in each row and column of the character table there is at most one pair of irrationalities. The only rows with irrationalities are those corresponding to $\lambda^\pm$ where $\lambda$ is a self-conjugate partitions such that the number of off-diagonal boxes in its Young diagram is odd. The only columns with irrationalities are of the classes of elements with cycle decomposition $(2m_1+1,\dotsc,2m_d+1)$, where $m_1>\dotsb > m_d$, and $\sum_{i=1}^d m_d$ is odd.

The only alternating groups $A_n$ with real character table are for the values $n=2,5,6,10,14$.

James and Kerber discuss the characters of alternating groups, but do not give any interesting examples. Frobenius (Georg Ferdinand Frobenius. 1901. ‘Über die Charaktere der alternirenden Gruppe.’
[On the characters of alternating groups.] S’ber Akad. Wiss. Berlin, 303–15) has computations for $A_8$. [My book](https://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/rtcv/) has many examples and a more detailed explanation in Chapters 4 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

As a related question, one can ask how many of the irreducible characters have only real values.  It is known that this is the same as the number of real conjugacy classes, where $[x]$ is said to be real iff it is the same as $[x^{-1}]$.  Let $G$ be the alternating group on $n$ letters, let $S$ denote the corresponding symmetric group, and let $\epsilon\colon S\to\mathbb{Z}/2$ be the map with kernel $G$.  If $x\in G$ then there is an obvious way (starting from a disjoint cycle decomposition) to construct $y\in S$ with $yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}$.  If $m_i$ is the number of $i$-cycles in $x$ then it works out that 
$$ \epsilon(y) = \sum_im_i\lfloor i/2\rfloor = \sum_j (m_{4j+2}+m_{4j+3}). $$
If $\epsilon(y)=0$ then clearly $[x]$ is real. If $\epsilon(y)=1$ then $[x]$ is real iff there is an odd permutation $z$ that commutes with $x$ (so we can replace $y$ by $yz$).  I think that this holds iff there is an even $i$ with $m_i>0$, or an odd $i$ with  $m_i>1$.  Thus, we see that $[x]$ is non-real iff it is a product of cycles of distinct odd lengths, an odd number of which are congruent to $3$ mod $4$.  There will be many classes like this when $n$ is large, so there will be many non-real irreducible characters.  It seems unlikely to me that each such character has only two non-real values, but I do not see a proof.  Anyway, I hope that this analysis may at least shed some light on the original question.